# VS code terminal disable previous commands output

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it Possible to disable/remove **Previous commands** output in VS code terminal default terminal is **Powershell** now if i type commands `pwd` and `dir` and then clear the screen by using `cls` command now if i type `dir` command again i am receving all previous commands output in terminal how can i fix this problem

**1st command output**

```
PS C:\Users\sadam\Desktop> pwd

Path
----
C:\Users\sadam\Desktop
```

**2nd command output**

```
PS C:\Users\sadam\Desktop> whoami
root\sadam
```

**3rd command output**

```
PS C:\Users\sadam\Desktop> dir


    Directory: C:\Users\sadam\Desktop


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         1/24/2022   8:53 PM            7.txt
d----        10/22/2021   9:46 PM            8
d----        11/16/2021   7:16 PM            del
d----        11/16/2021   8:52 PM            pcl
d----          1/9/2022  12:40 PM            ssssss
-a---         1/20/2022   6:41 PM         68 11.txt
```

**cleaning the screen by using** `cls` **command**

**typing again** `dir` **command & receving output of previous commands**

```
PS C:\Users\sadam\Desktop>cls
PS C:\Users\sadam\Desktop>

PS C:\Users\sadam\Desktop> pwd

Path
----
C:\Users\sadam\Desktop

PS C:\Users\sadam\Desktop> whoami
root\sadam

PS C:\Users\sadam\Desktop> dir


    Directory: C:\Users\sadam\Desktop


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         1/24/2022   8:53 PM            7.txt
d----        10/22/2021   9:46 PM            8
d----        11/16/2021   7:16 PM            del
...
...


PS C:\Users\sadam\Desktop> dir


    Directory: C:\Users\sadam\Desktop


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         1/24/2022   8:53 PM            7.txt
d----        10/22/2021   9:46 PM            8
d----        11/16/2021   7:16 PM            del
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is described in the bug-report
[Reopen: vscode terminal disrespects cls command in windows #45137](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45137).

This bug-report is titled "Reopen", because Microsoft keeps on closing it
whenever it is reported. Evidently, there is no intention of fixing it.

The bug seems to be that the `cls` command clears the screen, but does
not clear the scrollback buffer of the terminal, where the past events
still exist and are recalled when any scrolling is done.

The solution is to use
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.
This cleans out the Visual Studio Code console, rather than the screen.

As in some versions of VSCode (1.29 and above) this shortcut is missing,
it needs to be created as follows:

- Navigate to menu *File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts*
- Find `workbench.action.terminal.clear`
- To change its mapping, double-click and when prompted hold
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>K</kbd>.
  Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save.
- Right-click the entry and select "Change when expression".
  Type `terminalFocus` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is defined.

Another solution is to press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
and select `Terminal:clear`.

Still another
[solution](https://superuser.com/a/1553412/8672)
is:

> Use two commands together in keybindings.json:
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
>
> ```
>  {
>     "key": "ctrl+k",
>     "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
>     "args": { "text": "cls \u000D" },
>     "when": "terminalFocus" 
> },
>
> {
>     "key": "ctrl+l",
>     "command": "workbench.action.terminal.clear",
>     "when": "terminalFocus" 
> }
> ```